# Kotlin URL().readText(), how to convert string from return

Tags: android, utf-8, kotlin

I'm stacked by converting string, here is my code:

```
fun getCurrentTitle() {
    doAsync {
        val str = URL("http://10.0.0.8:4800/${Utils.TITL}").readText(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
        uiThread {
            current_song_title.text = str
            System.out.println(str)
        }
    }
}
```

here is string that i get returned (in TextView is same)

```
I/System.out: Ti�sto - On My Way
```

and in Web-Browser returns correct string

```
Tiėsto - On My Way
```

I dont have idea what i do wrong...

Thanks in advance!

> Edit
>   If someone have same issue, here is solution. Thans to **Vivick**
>
> val url = URL("http://10.0.0.8:4800/${Utils.TITL}").readText(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))

Comment: what do you get with a simple curl on that URL?

Comment: Maybe what you're displaying the text on doesn't handle utf-8

Comment: @s1m0nw1 curl returns TiÙsto - On My Way

Comment: @Vivick you have right, ISO-8859-1 handle it. Thank you!

Comment: @MilosLulic, rather than just edit the question, you or Vivick should also answer the question, so that it is marked as correct. Others searching in the future may not click into this question because it appears unanswered otherwise.

Comment: Please [don't edit answers into questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question). Post the answer as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As concluded in the comments, just utilize the ISO-8859-1 charset in order to see the characters you want.

(This is just a reiteration in order to get this post marked as solved)